# How to create a logfile when calling CPLEX from python

Tags: python-3.x, cplex

In the website of **https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/InteractiveOptimizer/solnOptions.html**
I knew that when CPLEX solved a problem,it will create a logfile named as "cplex.log", but when I use CPLEX to solve a problem in python, this file wasn't created. And I'm so confused about that if this problem have some matters with the difference of languages. I mean, when using CPLEX to solve a problem in MATLAB, Java or C++, logfile will be created, but not created in python.
I'm expecting for your help.Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `cplex.log` file is specific to the CPLEX interactive. It is *not* created automatically when using the other APIs (e.g., Python, Java, etc.). However, you can create it yourself doing the following (e.g., with the Python API):

```
cpx = cplex.Cplex()
cplexlog = "cplex.log"
cpx.set_results_stream(cplexlog)
cpx.set_warning_stream(cplexlog)
cpx.set_error_stream(cplexlog)
cpx.set_log_stream(cplexlog)
```

The argument to the `set_*_stream` methods can be a path (as above) or a file-like object, so you can do pretty much anything you want (e.g., implement a file-like object to display output on stdout but also write it to a log file, etc.). See the documentation for [set_results_stream](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html#set_results_stream) for more details.

NOTE: There is some output that gets displayed from the interactive that is not available in the other APIs. However, you should be able to recreate it easily as all of the information is available through the programmatic APIs.

**EDIT**:

With CPLEX 12.10 using a filename with the `set_results_stream`, `set_warning_stream`, `set_error_stream`, and `set_log_stream` methods has been removed (see announcement [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes12100/removed.html)). Instead, a file-like object should be passed in, like so:

```
with cplex.Cplex() as cpx, \
     open("cplex.log") as cplexlog:
    cpx.set_results_stream(cplexlog)
    cpx.set_warning_stream(cplexlog)
    cpx.set_error_stream(cplexlog)
    cpx.set_log_stream(cplexlog)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Because of your help, I create a logfile successfully. But I'm so sorry to say that I got a new problem, that after I opened this file, nothing is recorded. And I think maybe the reason is that I didn't build a model in a standard way as cplex's example told, and I built a model in the module named as picos(https://picos-api.gitlab.io/picos/). When I tried to solve the problem, I just called the cplex with a word "picos.Problem().solve(solver=cplex)", is there a way to fix this? I'm so sorry to bother you but sill expecting your reply.Thanks again.

Comment: I think your original question has been answered. You should create a new question; it sounds like it's specific to the picos library and off topic here.

Comment: I got it, Thanks so much.

Comment: It didn't work for me. It raises this error "output file must have a write method". According to the documentation cited, it should work, since I just need to provide a file name.

Comment: @NaraBegnini: I've updated my answer; maybe that will help.

Comment: Is it also possible to parse the log to the log file AND display the log in the Python terminal? Using this approach, I get the log file after solving but cannot track the progress on the screen any more.